# Content listing to show custom fields of associated terms instead of title

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Drupal 7 with views 3.

I have a Content Type of "Flag" associated with a vocabulary named "Colors", and its terms are Red, Blue, White, Yellow, etc. Each color has a custom field named field_color_image where I upload a small color thumbnail.

Currently I have a following 'Content' view set up, that lists flag names and it's colors(terms).

In my Views, the Fields is set to display 'Content: title' and 'Content: field_color'

The output looks like this:

```
- American Flag
Terms : Red, Blue, White

- Russia Flag
Terms : Red, Blue, White

- Sweden Flag
Terms : Blue, Yellow
```

How can I output the field_color_image of the term instead of the title?

Notes: I have checked under replacement patterns and they don't have custom taxonomy field support.

Thanks.

Comment: Please state what do you mean by "vocabulary"? Have you used taxonomy to create color "terms"?

Comment: @Ali Hi, there are terms already. The name of the vocabulary associated with the content type Flag is Colors, and it has color names as its terms.

Answer (score 0):

In Views under `Contextual Filters` select your vocabulary field. Now you can find your required image field under `add` button in fields. Add that field to your view.